# how to change pictures after few seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to create a simple slideshow using javascript. i have write some code but it doesn't work properly.

```js
/**
 * Created by jahid on 3/7/2016.
 */
var slideimg = new Array();

slideimg[0] = new Image();
slideimg[1] = new Image();
slideimg[2] = new Image();
slideimg[3] = new Image();
slideimg[0].src = "images/polygon1.png";
slideimg[1].src = "images/polygon2.png";
slideimg[2].src = "images/polygon3.png";
slideimg[3].src = "images/polygon4.png";

var i=0;
function slideit(){
    document.getElementById('polygon').src = slideimg[i].src;
    if(i < 4){
        i++;
    }
    else
        i = 0;
    setTimeout("slideit()",3000);
}
```

and my html codes are here...

```html
<div class="box1">
 <img src="images/polygon1.png" id="polygon" width="100%" height="220" onload="slideit()">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your html code

Comment: `<div class="box1">
     <img src="images/polygon1.png" id="polygon" width="100%" height="220" onload="slideit()">
    </div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a little bit change your code and start function:

```
var i=0;
function slideit() {
    if (i >= 4) {
        i = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('polygon').src = slideimg[i].src;
    i += 1;
    setTimeout(slideit,3000);
}
slideit();
```

Comment: but it still doesn't change my pictures

Comment: I edited the code above. It words in for me in Chrome. Does your element with id `polygon` is `img` tag?

Comment: Yes...my element with id polygon is img tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop the `"` and `()` in your `setTimeout()` call:

```
setTimeout(slideit,3000);
```

You are currently calling a string instead of a function.

Comment: There will be no issues, if you pass it as a string. It will be `eval`uated under the hood.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that! So, as @Dmitriy aswered, he just needs to call the `slideit()` method after declaring it.